# Get artifacts URL after rtUpload in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

Im using jenkins artifactory plugin and uploading tar file using rtUpload.
Is there a way to get the artifact URI when it finished?

It does print it as a log :

> [Pipeline] rtUpload
>
> 17:01:50 [consumer_0] Deploying artifact: http://x.x.x.x:8081/artifactory/my-local/snapshot/mor_v.tar.gz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functionality is only available on scripted pipeline at the moment, and is described in the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-GettingDependenciesandArtifactsfromtheBuild-Info).

For example:

```
node {
def server = Artifactory.server SERVER_ID
def uploadSpec = readFile 'uploadSpec.json'
def buildInfo = server.upload spec: uploadSpec

if (buildInfo.getArtifacts().size() > 0) {
    def localPath = buildInfo.getArtifacts()[0].getLocalPath()
    def remotePath = buildInfo.getArtifacts()[0].getRemotePath()
    def md5 = buildInfo.getArtifacts()[0].getMd5()
    def sha1 = buildInfo.getArtifacts()[0].getSha1()
    echo remotePath
}

server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
}
```