# Get Artifactory URL from Jenksfile and email it

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I'm using a Jenkinsfile to upload some artifacts to Artifactory. Once this is complete, I want to be able to send an email with the download link for the artifacts. Currently, the best I can find is to send the directory where the file is and then navigate to it. Is there a way to capture the full download URL without having to go into the build log or having to find it to download it? I've include my Jenkinsfile Stage below.

```
stage('Artifactory') {
            when{
                anyOf{
                    branch 'UploadBranch'
                }
            }
            steps{
                rtUpload (
                    serverId: 'Artifactory_Server',
                    spec: '''{
                        "files": [
                            {
                                "pattern": "path/to/file/*",
                                "target": "Project/${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}/folder1/"
                            },
                            {
                                "pattern": "path/to/other/file/*",
                                "target": "Project/${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}/folder2/"                       
                            }
                        ]}
                    '''
                )           
            }
            post {
                always {
                    emailext attachLog: true, body: '''A new file has been uploaded into Artifactory.
                    Please find link below:
                    https://fake.artifactory.com/Project/${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}''', subject: 'New file in Artifactory', recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
                    cleanWs()
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see from the snippet above, I won't know the file name or which folder it will end up in ahead of time, so I'd need a way of capturing the upload log. Is this even something I can do in a Jenkinsfile?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471011/get-artifacts-url-after-rtupload-in-jenkins-pipeline/59477013#59477013

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar job setup, it's working fine till now.

Once you upload the artifact then follow the below steps.
Steps...

1. Make a Jfrog Artifact search of the recently uploaded item in a particular location e.g. in your case it's [https://fake.artifactory.com/Project/${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}/folder2/](https://fake.artifactory.com/Project/$%7BBUILD_TIMESTAMP%7D/folder2/)
2. Save the output in a file or some Environment Variable.
3. Retrieve the value of the same Environment variable in your message.